# Using glmulti function to extract p-value

Tags: r

I am using the package `glmulti` to find the "best" model for

```
mo <- glm(a ~ x + y + z, data=data, family=binomial)
test <- glmulti(mo, family = binomial, level=1, crit="aicc")
```

However, I am more interested in the p-values of x in all models (to find the best p-value). How can I extract them from all models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test outputs the best model, but gmulti allows you to see all the models. You can see all other models with their weights and aicc values with [weightable](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/glmulti/docs/weightable)

```
weightable(test)
```

Here is a loop through the resultset, build glm model with as.formula() and extract the p-values of x (if present) from the summaries.

```
library(glmulti)

iris2 <- iris
iris2$virginica <- iris$Species == "virginica"

mo = glm(virginica ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris2, family="binomial")

test <- glmulti(mo, family = binomial, level=1, crit="aicc")

tbl <- weightable(test)
nrows <- nrow(tbl)

for (i in 1:nrows) {
    formulaTest <- as.character(tbl[i,]$model)
    model = glm(as.formula(formulaTest), data=iris2, family="binomial")

    print(paste("Formula: ", formulaTest))
    print(summary(model)$coefficients[,4])
}

[1] "Formula:  virginica ~ 1 + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width"
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  0.03522621   0.07853563   0.04033382   0.04534974 
[1] "Formula:  virginica ~ 1 + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width"
 (Intercept) Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  0.09720282   0.30318813   0.13585218   0.04653593   0.06052811 
[1] "Formula:  virginica ~ 1 + Sepal.Length + Petal.Length + Petal.Width"
 (Intercept) Sepal.Length Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  0.02770914   0.07149206   0.02891997   0.02830069 
...
```

If you want to employ advanced model selection, you could even combine top models, as described here: http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/2/20/model-selection-drug.html

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm not so experienced in r programming and don't know how to create this loop... can you help me please?

Comment: i've added the function to my initial reply.

Comment: many thanks, it works! instead of printing the p-values, I add them directly into a data frame